# How can I loop the function in Python, so my script runs all the time?

Tags: python, function, loops, repeat

I want to run this script repeatedly, so the ping doesn't stop and continue endlessly.
I tried to loop the function with range and while i<9999 but I am taking error " TypeError: ping_ip() missing 1 required positional argument: 'current_ip_address'. If I copy/paste the function all and all over again in the script it runs to the next one without problem. Any idea please? :

```
import platform
import win32api
import winsound



def ping_ip(current_ip_address):
        try:
            output = subprocess.check_output("ping -{} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system().lower(
            ) == "windows" else 'c', current_ip_address ), shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
            if 'unreachable' in output:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        except Exception:
                return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_ip_address = ['192.168.8.103', '0.0.0.0']
    for each in current_ip_address:
        if ping_ip(each):
            print(f"{each} is available")
        else:
            winsound.Beep(400, 1000)
            win32api.MessageBox(0, each, 'Device is down')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wraps the `for` loop, inside a

- `while True` to run indefinitly, wait for you to stop the program
- `for i in range(X)` to run X times

You can also add a `time.sleep` to  pause a bit between each call

```py
def ping_ip(current_ip_address):
    try:
        mode = 'n' if platform.system().lower() == "windows" else 'c'
        output = subprocess.check_output("ping -{} 1 {}".format(mode, current_ip_address),
                                         shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
        return 'unreachable' not in output
    except Exception:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    current_ip_address = ['192.168.8.103', '0.0.0.0']
    while True:
        for each in current_ip_address:
            if ping_ip(each):
                print(f"{each} is available")
            else:
                winsound.Beep(400, 1000)
                win32api.MessageBox(0, each, 'Device is down')

        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
while(True):
```

This will continue running

Answer (score 0):

To add on @Shubham Periwal's answer, you can use a variable to make your infinite loop a bit more controllable:

```
switched_on = True
while switched_on:
    do_things()
    
    if condition:
       switched_on = False
```